# python tutorials for robot setup tf and sensors

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Very new to ROS.....please excuse

**core server navigation visualisation etc**
maverick
2.6.35-28-generic
ros-cturtle-core (synaptics version) 1.0.0-s1302849017~maverick

**robot node**
ubuntu-10-04 architecture armel ( beagle board xM )
ros cturtle compiled on board from svn

**Outline**
Was planning to implement ROS via python to control.read data from personal arduino robot. My arduino is working well so I do n't really want to start integrating other's libraries into it at the moment.

**Progress**
Working through the tutorials and most work, transform listener/broadcaster mostly work, but the introductions to time fail.

Now trying to work through the c/cpp tutorials for robot setup and laser sensor.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials

**Issue**

I really want to work in python if I can, are there tutorials for these or do you have to setup in C and then use python in a restricted manner?

Thanks

Dave

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9801/python-tutorials-for-robot-setup-tf-and-sensors/) by [davo](https://answers.ros.org/users/456/davo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2011-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation stack setup is basically robot configuration setup, i.e. provide laser, odometry, and especially tf + writing config and launch files for the nav stack.
The data can come from any ROS node (i.e. also python), you will just need to publish odometry and tf.
The config and launch files are independent of python (or c++).

The navstack tutorials are mostly C++ independent. The example code is in C++ but besides showing you which values to fill, you should be able to do the same things in python.

It might be a good idea to do the [python tf tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials) and you should know how to write a broadcaster from the general ROS tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1